# Generate GEOJSON using pandas datframe

Tags: python, pandas, geojson

I have a pandas dataframe that contains Longitude,Latitude, City, State,Timestamp.
I have created one additional column as geometry that is a combination of [Latitude,Longitude].

I wanted to generate a geojson file that contains geomatory information on basis of city something like that
https://github.com/adilmoujahid/kaggle-talkingdata-visualization/blob/master/input/geojson/china_provinces_en.json

Comment: Alright, what is the problem?

Comment: Can you share the code how to generate it. I have Dataframe with columns mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all rows of the dataframe and build up a dict with the geojson structure. Afterwards, you can dump the dict to a geojson file.

```
import json

geojson = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": []}

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    feature = {"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [row['Longitude'], row['Latitude']]}, "properties": {"city": row['city']}}
    geojson['features'].append(feature)

with open('result.geojson', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(geojson, fp)
```