# How do I make a geojson file from DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, geojson

I want to make a file (geojson) from my DataFrame.

[image]

like the below geojson
[image]

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: In which format are the coordinates stored? Are they in the in "polygon" column?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400918/12780418 for a similar question with point geometries.

Comment: thanks a lot. this is really useful for me. 
the column, polygon has multiple latitudes and longitudes like [128.12345,36.12345],[128.12344,36.12344],...
is this code working with like this dataframe? i'll try it first :)